# Kaluza-Klein Christoffel Symbols

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, differential-geometry, potential, kaluza-klein

I have a question regarding the connection coefficients as they pertain to the following paper: http://www.weylmann.com/kaluza.pdf . When I try to calculate the 4D Christoffel symbols from the 4D part of the 5D metric $\tilde{g}_{\mu \nu}=g_{\mu \nu}+kA_\mu A_\nu$ I get an extra term that shouldn't be there. I get:

$$\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\mu \nu }=\frac{1}{2}\tilde{g}^{\lambda \sigma}(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{\nu \sigma}+\partial_\nu \tilde{g}_{\mu \sigma}-\partial_\sigma \tilde{g}_{\mu \nu})$$

$$=\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu \nu }+\frac{k}{2} g^{\lambda \sigma}(\partial_\mu (A_\nu A_\sigma)+\partial_\nu (A_\mu A_\sigma)-\partial_\sigma (A_\mu A_\nu))$$

$$=\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu \nu }+\frac{k}{2} g^{\lambda \sigma}(A_\mu (\partial_\nu A_\sigma -\partial_\sigma A_\nu)+A_\nu (\partial_\mu A_\sigma -\partial_\sigma A_\mu)+A_\sigma (\partial_\mu A_\nu +\partial_\nu A_\mu ))$$

$$=\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu \nu }+\frac{k}{2} g^{\lambda \sigma}(A_\mu F_{\nu \sigma }+A_\nu F_{\mu \sigma}+A_\sigma (\partial_\mu A_\nu +\partial_\nu A_\mu ))$$

According to the paper the $A_\sigma$ term shouldn't be there, but I can't figure out how to make it go away. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I should note that there appear to be a number of errors in the paper, but I'm unsure as to whether or not this is an error as well. For example, in the Lorentz force law he derives there is a factor 1/2 in front of the second term on the RHS which keeps the equation from being gauge-invariant (so the 1/2 should just be 1). 

He also says second term "has no classical correspondence" although a quick check reveals that $k(u^5 + A_\mu u^\mu)$ is the Noether conserved momentum about the 5th dimension which can be associated with charge. So the second term is just an illusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed a term in expanding the upper-indexed metric. The full version is below:
\begin{align}
\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\mu\nu} & = \frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda X} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{\nu X} + \partial_\nu \tilde{g}_{\mu X} - \partial_X \tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda\sigma} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{\nu\sigma} + \partial_\nu \tilde{g}_{\mu\sigma} - \partial_\sigma \tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}\right) + \frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda5} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{\nu5} + \partial_\nu \tilde{g}_{\nu5} - \partial_5 \tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} g^{\lambda\sigma} \left(\partial_\mu \left(g_{\nu\sigma} + k A_\nu A_\sigma\right) + \partial_\nu \left(g_{\mu\sigma} + k A_\mu A_\sigma\right) - \partial_\sigma \left(g_{\mu\nu} + k A_\mu A_\nu\right)\right) \\
& \quad \qquad + \frac{1}{2} \left(-A^\lambda\right) \left(\partial_\mu \left(k A_\nu\right) + \partial_\nu \left(k A_\mu\right) - \partial_5 \left(g_{\mu\nu} + k A_\mu A_\nu\right)\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} g^{\lambda\sigma} \left(\partial_\mu g_{\nu\sigma} + \partial_\nu g_{\mu\sigma} - \partial_\sigma g_{\mu\nu}\right) + \frac{k}{2} g^{\lambda\sigma} \left(\partial_\mu \left(A_\nu A_\sigma\right) \partial_\nu \left(A_\mu A_\sigma\right) - \partial_\sigma \left(A_\mu A_\nu\right)\right) \\
& \quad \qquad - \frac{k}{2} A^\lambda \left(\partial_\mu A_\nu + \partial_\nu A_\mu\right) \\
& = \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu} + \frac{k}{2} g^{\lambda\sigma} \left(A_\mu \left(\partial_\nu A_\sigma - \partial_\sigma A_\nu\right) + A_\nu \left(\partial_\mu A_\sigma - \partial_\sigma A_\mu\right) + A_\sigma \left(\partial_\mu A_\nu + \partial_\nu A_\mu\right)\right) \\
& \quad \qquad - \frac{k}{2} g^{\lambda\sigma} A_\sigma \left(\partial_\mu A_\nu + \partial_\nu A_\mu\right) \\
& = \Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu} + \frac{k}{2} \left(A_\mu F_{\nu\sigma} + A_\nu F_{\mu\sigma}\right).
\end{align}
This is because we have
\begin{cases}
\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu} + k A_\mu A_\nu \\
\tilde{g}_{\mu5} = k A_\mu \\
\tilde{g}_{55} = k
\end{cases}
*and also*
\begin{cases}
\tilde{g}^{\mu\nu} = g^{\mu\nu} \\
\tilde{g}^{\mu5} = -A_\mu \\
\tilde{g}^{55} = \frac{1}{k} + A_\mu A^\mu.
\end{cases}

Comment: Perfect! Silly mistake on my part, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand in the above answer the coefficient $k$ is taken to be constant. Since I am doing very similar calculations right now, let me just put the results for the full Christoffel symbols, using the metric with all coefficients depending on the base space. I am using my own notations, but everything is defined below.

The metric and its inverse are given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& g^{\mu\nu}=
\begin{bmatrix}
f^{-2}(-1+f^3\omega^p\omega_p) & -f \omega^n \\
- f \omega^m  & f h^{mn}
\end{bmatrix}, && 
g_{\mu\nu}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-f^2 & -f^2 \omega_m\\
-f^2 \omega_m & f^{-1}h_{mn}-f^2 \omega_m\omega_n
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The corresponding vielbein takes the following form
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\hat{e}^0&=f(dt+\omega),\\
\hat{e}^a&=f^{-1/2}e^a,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\hat{e}^A\hat{e}^B\eta_{AB}=ds^2$ and $e_m^{\bar{m}}e_n^{\bar{n}}\eta_{\bar{m}\bar{n}}=h_{mn}$.

All small Latin indices are raised and lowered by the space metric $h_{mn}$. The Christoffel symbols $\hat{\Gamma}_{\mu\nu}{}^\rho$ of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ then read
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\Gamma}_{00}{}^\mu&=fg^{\mu m}\partial_mf,\\
\hat{\Gamma}_{0n}{}^0&=f^{-1}\partial_n f-f^2\omega_n \omega^m\partial_m f-\frac12f^3\omega^mF_{mn},\\
\hat{\Gamma}_{0m}{}^k&=f^2\partial^kf \omega_m+\frac12f^3 F^k{}_{m},\\
\hat{\Gamma}_{mn}{}^0&=\nabla_{(n}\omega_{n)}+3f^{-1}\omega_{(m}\partial_{n)}f-\frac12f^{-1}\partial_\omega f h_{mn}+f^3\omega^k\omega_{(m}F_{n)k}-f^2\partial_\omega f \omega_m\omega_n,\\
\hat{\Gamma}_{mn}{}^k&=\Gamma_{mn}{}^k+f^3F^k{}_{(m}\omega_{n)}+f^2\partial^kf\omega_m\omega_n-f^{-1}\partial_{(m}f\delta^k_{n)}+\frac12f^{-1}\partial^kfh_{mn},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where we define as usual the field strength $F_{mn}=2\partial_{[m}\omega_{n]}$ and denote $\omega^k\partial_k=:\partial_\omega$. Note the $g^{\mu m}$ in the first line, that actually contains some powers of $f$ as well.

Decomposition of the spin connection then reads
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\omega}^{\bar{m}\bar{n}}&=\omega^{\bar{m}\bar{n}}-f^{-1}\partial^{[\bar{m}}fe^{\bar{n}]}-\frac12f^3 F^{\bar{m}\bar{n}}(dt+\omega),\\
\hat{\omega}^{\bar{m}\bar{0}}&=f^{\frac12}\partial^{\bar{m}}f \omega+\frac{1}{2}f^{\frac 32}F^{\bar{m}}{}_{\bar{n}}e^{\bar{n}},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $e^{\bar{m}}=e^{\bar{m}}_mdx^m$ is the  vielbein generating the metric $h_{mn}$. My definition (in all dimensions) for the spin connection is:
\begin{equation}
\omega_m{}^{\bar{m}\bar{n}}=-\Gamma_{mn}{}^ke^{n\bar{n}}e_k^{\bar{m}}+e^{k\bar{n}}\partial_m e_k^{\bar{m}}.
\end{equation}
This follows from the vielbein postulate 
\begin{equation}
0=\nabla_m[\Gamma,\omega]e^{\bar{m}}_n=\partial_m e^{\bar{m}}_n-\Gamma_{mn}{}^ke^{\bar{m}}_k- \omega_m{}^{\bar{m}\bar{n}}e_{\bar{m}n}
\end{equation}